# Instead of space expanding maybe atoms are shrinking?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

Naturally we would not be able to detect this effect directly by measuring the size of objects using rulers because any such ruler would be shrinking too. Also cosmological redshift can be explained by either stretching photon wavelengths or increasing energies of absorber atoms.

But I think the following experiment would be able to detect if atoms are shrinking.

Consider two charged objects with mass $m$ and charge $q$ separated by distance $d$.

Let us assume that the system is stable so that the electrostatic repulsion of the charges $q$ is balanced by the gravitational attraction of the masses $m$.

Thus we have:

$$\frac{q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 d^2}=\frac{Gm^2}{d^2}\tag{1}$$

Now in natural units ($\hbar=c=4\pi\epsilon_0=1$) the gravitational constant $G=1/M_{Pl}^2$ where $M_{Pl}$ is the Planck mass.

Thus equation $(1)$ becomes:

$$\frac{q^2}{d^2}=\frac{m^2/M_{Pl}^2}{d^2}\tag{2}$$

The balance of electrical and gravitational forces does not depend on the separation $d$ so that finally we have the simple equality

$$q=\frac{m}{M_{Pl}}\tag{3}$$

Now if atomic distances are shrinking then atomic rest-mass energies are increasing with the scale factor $a(t)$. But both $m$ and $M_{Pl}$ expand by the same scale factor $a(t)$ so that equation $(3)$ remains the same.

Thus the separation $d$ of the objects does not change with time.

But if our rulers are shrinking then we will measure the separation distance $d$ apparently increasing.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Wetterich proposed a similar idea a few years ago.  It's described at http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6878.

Comment: The space expansion measured is not measurable in the lab, it is observed over cosmic distances,

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/123208

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we know the universe is expanding, and not that its contents are shrinking?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43072/)

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate because I describe an experiment that could be performed to check whether atomic energies are changing with cosmological time.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure now if this experiment can distinguish shrinking atoms from expanding space.

Comment: @ John Eastmond --You may want to see a comment I just posted on the answer, to another question, which is supposed to have answered your own as well.

Comment: @Edouard I have calculated that the canonical energy $E=-\partial L/\partial \dot{x}^0$, of a mass at rest, with respect to the co-ordinate basis $\partial/\partial x^\alpha$ is proportional to the scale factor $a(t)$. This leads to $G\propto 1/a^2$ in the co-ordinate basis. If we take the vacuum energy density to be constant (as it must for Lorentz invariance) then the FRW equation implies that $a(t)\propto t$. We can then either take the co-ordinate basis view that particle energies are increasing or we can rescale to get a constant G and an expanding space.