# Tempering of length and time

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

Suppose we are told that the linear size of everything in the universe has been doubled overnight. If we are told to measure the sizes, what will we do. I don't think we are going to measure  everything by scale. What should we do to check the truth of statement then?
In my view i think that speed of light is not changed,so if we use it to measurement, it's gonna helpful. The problem arises when i thought what will happen if time start running at half the speed? I m stuck here now

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47259/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic How can i remove this BADGE of DUPLICATE.

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra,What do you mean by 'BADGE OF DUPLICATE'?

Comment: The question of which you all are talking about simply ask about gravitation effect.I m asking about measurements of things.

Comment: @ItachíUchiha BADGE of DUPLICATE shows my frustration.But sorry for that.

Comment: The answer is in there though. If you double everything then by what standard would you know that things have changed? We measure things relative to other objects in space. Time is also relative to your point of view. So without a baseline of what was original then you cannot know what changed.

Comment: Whatever changed ,it has no  significance since  i know that speed of light is not changed.(in my view) Can't i measure everything with reference to it.

Comment: I see,You are new to site.You will slowly get accustomed to the rules.

Comment: If i would be satisfied with those answer why would i ask a new one.I just want a satisfactory answer,what to do now??