# Suppose you are told that the linear size of everything in the universe has been doubled overnight. Can you test this statement?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, distance

Suppose you are told that the linear size of everything in the universe has been doubled overnight. Can you test this statement by measuring sizes with a meter stick? Can you test it by the fact that the speed of light is a universal constant and has not changed? What will happen if all the clocks in the universe also start running at half the speed?

This question demands to be answered on the basis of the 2018 CGPM definitions for the Fundamental Units. (where the constant values were assigned to the fundamental units)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What if the size of the Universe doubled?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721/)

Comment: Our yardsticks are fixed by EM/atomic physics, so then, α. This is how we monitor the universe expanding continuously (not overnight).

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am new to this platform and the site was not excepting my question as the title. I would like to apologise for the inconvinience

Comment: @NiharKarve Thankyou. This post helped to answer my question

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47259/2451