# What if everything doubled linearly?

Tags: cosmology, mass, space-expansion, universe, distance

There is a question that goes:

Suppose you are told that the linear size of everything in the universe has been doubled overnight. Can you test it by using the fact that the speed of light is a universal constant and has not changed? What will happen if all the clocks in the universe also start running at half the speed?

My doubt is with the **approach** that whether this can this be answered using **Mass**? Since that remains unchanged? If so, how? And if not, Why not?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47259/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The linked questions don’t answer the doubt about mass which seemed like a good approach to me. The answer below by Naveen V clarifies that directly.

Comment: I suppose the sudden change overnight you mentioned has to do with the magic spell that is to be broken at midnight. Usually this sort of cosmic phenomenon would leave some kind of experimentally measurable traces such as a glass slipper.

Comment: @MadMax Maybe something from MCU lol, the glass slipper’s too basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very vague to use it with mass , first case everything is doubled and the mass of an object remains the same and is more widely distributed decreasing density ( highly unlikely sometimes this breaks the object because bonds could be weak) , hence the second case is If an object doubles its length it must acquire some new mass , it cant be unchanged  through the doubling of sizes is what I think. You can check it via the speed of light because it is an universal constant and doesn't change in any reference frame and we can use that to measure the doubling of sizes overnight , and if clocks also run at half speed no difference is found as due to special relativity the reference frame with which light travels a greater distance than normal , its time must increase to compensate. When the increased time is compensated by the decreased clocks , we wouldn't notice anything